# Converting integer to string in Java

Tags: java

I have a class with some integer member, and after i get that value, I have to place it in TextView, but for that to be possible I need to convert it to string, so how do I do that?

```
Class class{

private int a;

    public int getA(){
       return a;
    }

};  
    class obj;
  String strA=obj.getA();
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(integerVal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
String.valueOf(intValue);
```

or

```
new Integer(intValue).toString();
```